Davening in the times of the first Bait Hamikdash
In likuttei torah Perek 4 it is written

כמו במקדש ראשון שלא היו מתפללין לפי שהיה שכלם בהיר בשחקים כל היום לראות ולהבין פלאות א״ס ב״ה

Loosely translated- like in the first Bait Hamikdash where they didn't daven...
What is the source that they didn't daven in the times of the first Bait Hamikdah?

https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=13837

You omitted the phrase immediately preceding the one you quoted: " ומדאורייתא אין צריך כ״א ק״ש ומעט תפלה". In other words, the Alter Rebbe isn't saying that the people in the time of בית ראשון didn't pray daily, but rather it means that the standardized formulation of modern prayers (the core of which is the Shemoneh Esrei) was not yet established at that time.

@Fred feel free to edit it in
